# Ошибка в добавлении в переменную значения из sql таблицы по условию

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Выдает ошибку при компиляции, записывает в переменную нулевое значение, хотя считывает и место, и ряд.
В таблице существует соответствующая запись.
Не могу понять в чем ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LOVENANDLER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Cinema;Integrated Security=True");

con.Open();
int selected_row = seats.SelectedIndex / 18 + 1;//выбранный ряд
int seat = Int32.Parse(SelectedSeat.Text);//выбранное место
string selectID_seatQuery = "SELECT ID_seat FROM Seats WHERE Number_Of_Seat = '" + seat + "' and Number_Row = '" + selected_row +"'";
SqlCommand selectID_seat = new SqlCommand(selectID_seatQuery, con);
int ID_seat = selectID_seat.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

Метод `ExecuteNonQuery` возвращает количество изменённых записей и используется с
INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE. А так как вы не меняли записи вам вернулся 0.

Для получения результата Select используйте метод `ExecuteReader`.
Больше инфы тут: https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.6.php.